# GitLab Page 404's when attempting to access a specific path

Tags: angular, gitlab, gitlab-pages

I setup a GitLab Page that uses a custom domain and it serves up an Angular application. If I go to `mywebsite.com` it works and I can navigate around the app no problem.

If I attempt to access the page via `mywebsite.com/about` (a valid path), for example, it 404's. The routes are handled correctly in the Angular app and should work since I've used this same routing code in other projects with no problems.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is because it's an Angular app and since they only generate one `index.html`, any attempt to resolve other paths fail since `about.html` doesn't exist.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-pages/issues/23